# ES2015 function name attribute?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
var person = {
  sayName() {
    console.log(this.name);
  },
  get firstName() {
    return "Nicholas";
  }
};

person.sayName.name   // "sayName"
person.firstName.name // "get firstName"
```

I just saw an example,`person.firstName.name` expected output

```
get firstName
```

but what I got by babel was `undefined`, deeply troubled me!

Comment: `expected output get firstName` - where did you get this idea?

Comment: `person.firstName` returns a string not an object.

Comment: Perhaps the example you just saw was incorrect - we only have your say so that such an example exists, and seeing as that code outputs `undefined` in ES2015 environments (like node.js for example) I'm convinced that you have either misunderstood the "example" or the "example" is just plain wrong - no need to be deeply troubled by incorrect information'

Comment: @ Jaromanda X [link](http://es6.ruanyifeng.com/#docs/object#方法的-name-属性)See here,Chinese pages

Comment: @JaromandaX [link](http://es6.ruanyifeng.com/#docs/object#方法的-name-属性)See here,Chinese pages

Comment: This seems a fairly contrived example, why do you care what the "name" of the function assigned to the *sayName* property is? Depending on how the function is assigned to the property, its name can be any valid identifier, or undefined.

Comment: Babel only implements some of the cases of name inference.

Comment: @董崇洋 - you can post that link 1000 times, but there's no way I'm following a link to a page I can't understand that probably **just got it wrong** anyway - it's clear that no current ES2015 implementation does what **you** think it should, nor can I see how it could, given `person.firstName` is a String, not a function

Answer (score 4):

`firstName` is a getter function, so `person.firstName` calls that function, and returns the return value of that getter. These means that you are reading the name property of the returned `"Nicholas"` string, which does not have a `name` property (thus, `undefined`).

You could use [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) to get a reference to the getter function:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(person, 'firstName').get.name
```

#### Working Example:

```js
var person = {
  sayName() {
    console.log(this.name);
  },
  get firstName() {
    return "Nicholas";
  }
};

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(person, 'firstName').get.name);
```